# How To: Ribbon Options Language & their ToolTip Text Language = Same Site's Language?

Tags: 2010, ribbon, language

I have SPS 2010 Intranet site for a global company where each country has its own site. Of course, Each country's site has its own language (All SharePoint 2010 Language Packs are installed). Everything is working alright except that I have a problem which I need your help in it please.

My problem is: Assume that you are browsing the French Site, and you clicked on: Site Actions > Edit Page, now the upper Ribbon appears, But:

1. All the Ribbon Options/Commands are in English such as: (Save &
   Close, Check In, Past...etc) Why these commands/options do not
   appear in French instead of English?
2. Also, If you hover the mouse cursor on "Save & Close" icon, then,
   the ToolTip Text Message appears in Spanish language, not even in
   English nor French language.

So, Could you please help me out on how to resolve these two problems? How to make the language of the Ribbon Options and their ToolTip Text exactly the same language of the site?

Comment: Any help please ??? I can confirm that the language packs are installed correctly. Could you please guide me what configurations or settings I have to check? Or what areas in the environment or Central Admin I have to dig? Please waiting your help !